# how to read all second lines from txt files with php and put them in 1 variable

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting

I have a lot of .txt files which have several lines of content in it.
To grab all the txt files in the folder messages, i use this code:

```
// read all files in messages folder
$dir = 'messages/';
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($file = readdir($dh))!== false){
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { // This line strips out . & ..     
            $files_list[] = $file;                  
        }

    }
}
```

To get the second line form a txt file, i know i can use this:

```
$lines = file($file);
$secondline = $lines[1];
```

But how can i grab all the second lines from all the txt files and put it in a variable, so that i can sort it? Something like. `rsort($all_secondlines_allfiles);`

Comment: Do you mean all even-numbered lines, or Line 2 from each file?

Comment: I mean line 2 from each file

Comment: Not sure, but you could try  `$lines = file($dir . $file);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the second line into a global array then use r/sort() function to sort it as needed.

```
$globalArray = [];

$dir = 'messages/';
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($file = readdir($dh))!== false){
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { // This line strips out . & .. 
            $lines = file($dir.$file);
            $secondline = $lines[1];    
            $globalArray[] = $secondline;                 
        }
    }
sort($globalArray);
print_R($globalArray);
}
```

Comment: print_r gives me this output: `Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => )` and it should be `Array ([0]=>sec.line [1]=>sec.line [2]=>sec.line and so on...`

Comment: I think the issue might be that $file does not contain the dir path and as these files are located in the messages folder, you will need to add $dir to the file path. See my edit.